# variance estimation for fused lasso

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization, degrees-of-freedom, fused-lasso

In the paper [THE SOLUTION PATH OF THE GENERALIZED LASSO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1971) the authors derived degrees of freedom for the generalised lasso. Assume that $y\in\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, with $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\Sigma = diag(\sigma)$, and let us, for the sake of simplicity, consider the following regression
$$
\hat{\beta}^{FL}(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}) = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} \, \frac{1}{2} ||y - \beta||_{2}^{2} +\lambda_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |\beta_{i+1}- \beta_{i}|_{1} + \lambda_{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\beta_{i}|,
$$
which is fused lasso.

Then, in the paper it was shown that the unbiased estimate of risk $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mu_{i} - \beta_{i} )^{2}]$ is given by
$$
C_{p}(\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \beta_{i} )^{2} - n\sigma^{2} +2\sigma^{2}K,
$$
where
$$
K = \#\{\text{non-zero coefficient blocks in } \, \hat{\beta}^{FL}\}.
$$

Therefore, this can be used for model selection.

The question: how to estimate $\sigma$?

Comment: What does $C_p$ mean?  Could you explain the term $\mu_{i} - \beta_{i}$ why should we relate the coefficients $\beta$ with the means $\mu$? What are these $\beta$? Are they estimates for $\mu$?

Comment: Dear @SextusEmpiricus  $C_{p}$ is just a notation from the paper for the unbiased estimate of true risk. Next, for each $i$ we have one measurement. Then we approximate the signal in the way described above. This is called fussed lasso signal approximator.

Comment: So this is a very specific case of fused Lasso? For each observation $y$ you have a seperate parameter to predict that observation, and there are no regressor variables?

Comment: yes, and, according to the paper referenced above, it is called signal approximation

Comment: This might be relevant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallows%27s_Cp the $\sigma$ is probably an estimate and based on the residuals.